# Moviepy does not recognize resize function

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

I'm trying to write an app which resizes video files, and the easiest way to do that is moviepy. However, I can't use resize function of moviepy. It seems unsolved reference. Part of my code is here:

I tried to solve my problem using ffmpeg with subprocess, but it did not work.

```
from moviepy.editor import *

video_path = self.file_name2process.text()
video2process = VideoFileClip(video_path)
video2process_resized = video2process.resize(height=360)
video2process_resized.write_videofile("new.mp4")
```

It does not show up any error message, because it does not recognize resize part. Since it does not recognize resize part, it also does not allow me to use 'write_videofile' function. Somehow, when I look into 'VideoFileClip' module, I can see resize function there, but I cannot reach that.

Here is the screenshot: https://i.hizliresim.com/5NqQAL.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it shows resize as an unresolved reference, but does the job anyway.

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

disk_video_path = get_tmp_video_file_path(video)
clip = VideoFileClip(disk_video_path)

video_max_height = int(get_config_value(STORY_VIDEO_HEIGHT))

if clip.h > video_max_height:
    clip_resized = clip.resize(height=video_max_height)
    clip_resized.write_videofile(RESIZED_STORY_VIDEO_NAME, temp_audiofile="temp-audio.m4a",
                             remove_temp=True,
                             codec="libx264",
                             audio_codec="aac", fps=30,
                             logger=None, threads=4)
    clip.close()
```

[Screenshot](https://eksiup.com/p/kf246189bdw8)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling about it with blind eyes like I did: The resize function returns a copy of the resized clip. You need to reassign the variable!
I know Shivam's answer contains the solution, but I did not notice it until if found the answer explicitly on reddit.
The moviePy documentation is confusing because the example does not show the reassignment.

```
resizedClip = oldClip.resize(width=400)
```